# 3D pattern searching in a float[][]

Tags: java, search, design-patterns, matching

I have an array of float values which could be interpreted as a grayscale image or a 3D surface (heightmap).
For instance it may be a 10x10 array like this :

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 4 0 9 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 6 0 2 8 7 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 3 5 5 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm looking for a Java library (or efficient algorithm) to detect the presence and location of one (or more) pattern similar to a reference pattern, for instance I want to obtain the location (5,5) as a result no matter I was looking for :

```
2 8 7
3 5 5
6 2 1
```

or :

```
3 8 6
3 6 5
5 2 3
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How efficient this algorithm should be? Obviously, you can do it by n*n*m*m time. For better estimates you need some advanced techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of any Java libraries, but I would figure it wouldn't be too hard to program. This problem can be seen as a derivative of the sub-string problem, except you don't have a linear string. Here's some Java-ish pseudo-code that is probably pretty close.

```
for(int x = 0; x < heightmap.width(); ++x)
    for(int y = 0; y < heightmap.height(); ++y)
        if(find_pattern(x, y))
            // YAY! pattern starts at (x, y)

// start at (x, y) and find an exact match
boolean find_pattern(int x, int y)
{
      for(int xx = 0; xx < pattern.width(); ++x)
          for(int yy = 0; yy < pattern.width(); ++x)
              if(heightmap[x + xx][y + yy] != pattern[xx][yy])
                  return false;
      return true; 
}
```

This will find an exact match. If you want something, say plus or minus 2, then you will need a little extra logic in find_pattern() instead of the != comparison.

There may be some other algorithms that run better. This is probably the simplest to program. Complexity wise this runs in O(n^2 * m^2): given n is the width and height of the heightmap, and m is the width and height of the pattern.

NOTE: this does not do boundary checking!

If you implement boundary checking, it will cut down on the number of comparisons needed since obviously the above pattern cannot start in the two right-most columns of the height map. Interestingly enough, when you have boundary checking, the complexity goes to O(n^2) as the ratio n:m goes to either 1:1 or 0:1

Comment: Yep, thank you. I know it's a possibility to program a function like this, but I was wondering if there are some more efficient algorithms which can works well even for large data with low CPU use. For instance I heard about wavelet stuff but I didn't find any Java library to do this...

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to represent the data as a one-dimensional
array you essentially have a string (containing only numerical values)
which can be searched for patterns with regular expressions. In case
that's not possible with Java (i.e. creating a string of floats instead
of characters) it shouldn't be too hard to roll your own (simple)
implementation for matching regular expressions[1].

[1] http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-nfas-and-regular-expressions-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of image filtering. The most basic approach may be expressed this way:

```
for i in 0..image.height
  for j in 0..image.width
    result = 0
    for k in 0..pattern.height
      for l in 0..pattern.width
        if  i + k < image.height && j + l < image.width
          result += image[i + k][j + l] * pattern[k][l]
    if result > threshold
      /* Found a solution */
```

The number `threshold` is something you will have to find by trial and error for a given problem. Maybe it's a good idea to normalize the numbers first to be in the [0,1] interval. Then for example `result / (pattern.width * pattern.height) > 0.75` means something like "75% like the pattern".

Depending on the sizes of the image and the pattern this may be slow - in that case you may look into [Image Filtering in the Frequency Domain](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagefilter/)